What is the $n$-th digit of $\sqrt[n]{n}$ in base $n$?
I decided to explore the $n$-th digit of $\sqrt[n]{n}$ in Base $n$, expecting to find a nicely behaved sequence due to the use of a $n$ base. However, the sequence turned out to be quite irregular (probably the most irregular one I have ever seen):
Let $d_n$, $n\ge 2$ denote the $n$-th digit of $\sqrt[n]{n}$ when expressed in base $n$. For example, $d_2 = 1$, $d_3 = 2$, $d_4 = 2$, and so on. The sequence $\{d_n\}_{n=2}^{\infty}$ begins:

1, 2, 2, 1, 0, 6, 5, 4, 7, 7, 8, 3, 2, 13, 0, 7, 11, 18, 8, 7, 16, 21, 6, 10, 25, 10, 6, 19, 16, 13, 0, 19, 8, 28, 26, 2, 8, 17, 18, 38, 23, 30, 14, 26, 14, 22, 31, 39, 5, 11, 3, 25, 32, 8, 45, 55, 29, 5, 6, 1, 45, 43, 0, 1, 31, 20, 48, 66, 40

These are generated by this python code
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from decimal import Decimal
import decimal
decimal.getcontext().prec = 2000
Decimal(10)**(-2000)



B=[]
for N in range (2,100):
    x=Decimal(N**(1/N))
    s=x- Decimal(1)
    A=[]
    
    i=1
    while i <N+1:
        
        A.append(math.floor (N**i*s))
        s=s-Decimal(math.floor (N**i*s)/(N**i))
        i=i+1
    B.append(A[N-1])    
    

print(B)


My question is: Is there a closed form for this sequence? I think this sequence is sufficiently irregular that a closed form is impossible.

BTW python really struggles to find $d_n$ for $n\ge 150$ although in this plot I use $10^5$ decimals

I think my algorithm is not sufficient enough, surely the sequence won't be $0 $ for $n\ge 150$

a remark about your python code: the precision of the float N**(1/N) is not good enough for your calculation

@YvesDaoust What is the name of the 'decimal' in base 'n'?

@user8268 How to fix this?

In order to determine the $n$-th digit of $\sqrt[n]{n}$ in base $n$ you would have to compute $\sqrt[n]{n}$ with a precision of (approximately) $\log_{10}(n^n)$ decimal digits. That would be 326 decimal digits for $n=150$. I do not know if that is possible in Python.
